# Building a Modem Control Software: the connection part

Tags: c#, modem, at-command

I have a 3G modem, and the accompanied "Mobile Partner" software really s*cks, and I want to make my own. Currently, I've found out the following:

- Sending/Interpreting AT commands
- Setting the APN/PIN/Network Registration/...

These things were well-documented on many sites. But now I want to connect, and here the problems start:

If I try to do a `ATDT *99#`, which should dial the *99# number, I get the message `CONNECT`. But what do I need to do now? How do I tell windows to use the dial in network?

Is the '*99#' even the number I should dial? (I think so, because it's the default dialing number in the Mobile Partner application, and on OS X on my 3G modem)

I'm writing this program in C#.

Thank you!

Yvan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that you would need to solve this in code. It's more of a Windows configuration thing.

Most 3G modems install a modem driver - which is what your Provider's software is using to connect.

In Windows Vista / Windows 7, you just go and set up a new Dialup connection, select your 3G Modem, and enter the *99# number.

**Edit:** 
(Replying to question in comments)

If you want to create this connection on just your own, or maybe a handful of computers  then I would say it's quicker to do it by hand to set-up.  (It takes maybe a minute or two at most following the Networking wizard)

Once the connection is created, then you simply click Connect any time you want to dial the 3G Connection.

I've done this for several USB 3G dongles and built in 3G Modems - they've all worked fine.

I did look for ways to automate creation of Windows Dial-up networking connections, but I can't find any information.

I would suggest creating a new question on Superuser.com or perhaps Serverfault.com which is probably more suited to windows-administration tasks.

Comment: how do I automate this? Thx, Yvan

Comment: @Yvan - Updated my answer in reply to your question. Automating this task is something you're likely to get a better answer for on superuser.com or serverfault.com (sister sites for StackOverflow, dedicated to these kinds of things)